# Fixing max_user_connections in PHP class using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been adapting an older abstraction layer to use PDO but I am running into `user x has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections SQLSTATE[HY000] [1203]` errors when looping through large sets.  I have been reading on http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php but all of my attempts to unset the $dbh from within the loops result in errors  from having ended the connection.

Base class looks like

```
class DB {  
    public $pdo;
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect()
    {
         $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname;charset=utf8;", $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function __sleep()
    {
        return array('dsn', 'username', 'password');
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->connection = null;
        $this->pdo = null;
        unset($this->pdo);
    }

    // CRUD methods follow including

    function retrieve($where, $groupBy='', $order_by='') {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `$this->table` $where $groupBy $order_by"; 

        $q = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $q->execute();

        $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,get_class($this));
        // was $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,get_class($this));
        $this->query_log($query);
        $q = null;

        if ($result == 'NULL') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    } // retrieve()
```

And an example that has the errors would be

```
if (in_array($_GET['type'], $types)) {
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $rsObj = new ReservedSlug;
    if ($type == 'artist') {
        $obj = new CalendarArtist;
        $slugfield = 'urlSlug';
        $namefield = 'name';
    } else if ($type == 'event') {
        $obj = new CalendarEvent;
        $slugfield = 'urlSlug';
        $namefield = 'name';
    } else if ($type == 'location') {
        $obj = new Location;
        $slugfield = 'UrlSlug';
        $namefield = 'LocationName1';
    }
    $needslug = $obj->retrieve("TRIM(`$namefield`) != '' AND (`$slugfield` = '' OR `$slugfield` IS NULL) LIMIT 0,400");

            if ($needslug) {
                foreach ($needslug as $ns) {
                    $testslug = slugify($ns->$namefield);
                    list($reserved) = $rsObj->retrieve("`slug` = '$testslug' AND `type` = '$type'");
                    if (!$reserved) {
                        list($test) = $obj->retrieve("`$slugfield` = '$testslug'");
                        if ($test) {
                            for ($i = 2; $i < 26; $i++) {
                                list($test) = $obj->retrieve("`$slugfield` = '$testslug-$i'");
                                if (!$test) {
                                    $slug = $testslug . '-' . $i;
                                }
                            }
                        } else { // not found in table
                            $slug = $testslug;
                        }
                    } else { // was reserved
                        $slug = false;  
                    }
                    echo $ns->$namefield . " gets $slug<p>";
                } // foreach needslug       
            } // if needslug
        } // type found in array
```

So I need to understand how to not create new connections when an active connection is available and how to properly __destruct() these child objects.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use persistent connections. `$options = array(PDO:: ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, ...);`

Comment: Do not extend your application classes from DB. A slug is not a database.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois JFYI it will kill his server even FASTER. Using persistent connections to cure max connects is like extinguish a fire with gasoline

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm extending DB so each class has access to common CRUD functions.  How do the child classes do their CRUD without a connection or how do they have a connection without inheritance?

Comment: Do not make your crud class connect to db then

Comment: I'm not following.  CRUD modifies the database. Been using the abstraction layer 16 years without connection limit issues which I assume is due to way PHP and the mysql_ functions did trash collection.  I can see that I am failing to either destruct unused connection or re-use existing connections correctly but I do not see how your comment would be implemented.

Comment: EXACTLY the way you just said yourself: a connection have to be *reused,* not opened anew.

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes hence me coming to SO and asking asking how to change my code to handle this.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois after adding PDO:: ATTR_PERSISTENT => true I no longer see these errors but I really would have thought it would make it worse.  Thank you!  Want to add it as the answer?

Comment: From what I can tell after reading your question, you are asking rather how to close an existing connection.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks.  CharlotteDunois comment is working for me.

Comment: Oh, it's not for long. Just let your pool to warm up :)

Comment: I agree with others that using persistent connections and inheriting the DB class is 'less than optimal'. However, it works for you currently. Why? I think it is solely due to your use of 'CRUD'. Each object does one small db task then frees the connection, This allows it to be reused immediately by other objects. It is not as efficient as just reusing it but is far better then trying create many new connections which is what was happening before. End result imo, - using persistent connections is ok for your circumstances of very short queries. I think one connect would be enough but it works.